# Seeking information about Shaivite sect 'Thirikam' and its Tantra Shastras

Tags: scripture, tantra, shaivism, kashmiri-shaivism, sampradaya

I am seeking information about the Shaivite sect 'Thirikam' and its Tantra Shastras, which are  'Malini Vijayotharam', 'Sidhayogeshwarimatham', and 'Tantra Sadhbavam'.

Are the shastras available online?

Comment: I think MaliniVijaya Tantra is available.